# Joining two csv files with common columns

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to use the `df_merge` function to join two csv files together with their common columns, the thing is they have multiple common columns. Can I modify my codes to achieve that?

Here's an example of how the columns look like in my two csv files:

File 1:

> A B C D E

File 2:

> A Z B C R P D E

Here is my code

`df_merge = file2.merge(file1, left_on = "A", right_on = "E")`

But it does not seem to work as I will be getting duplicate variables in the merge file.

Comment: `df_merge = file2.merge(file1, on=[col for col in file1.columns if col in file2.columns])`?

Comment: How working `df_merge = file2.merge(file1)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all import the `pandas` library:

```
import pandas as pd
```

You can read the two csv files as below:

```
data = pd.read_csv('Train_Roll_Number.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
data1 = pd.read_csv('Train_RGB_Sketch.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
data.columns = ['A', 'E', 'B']
data1.columns = ['A', 'E', 'C']
```

I chose to store them to `data` and `data1`. Now, if you want to merge these dataframes on the field 'A' and 'E', use:

```
data = pd.merge(data, data1, on=['A', 'E'])
```

In the `on` argument, you can specify a list of fields you would like to merge the two csv files on.

Comment: Good approach. `on` kwarg is so handy!

Comment: @Swadhikar, indeed!

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement, you need to find first common column names and pass to `on` operator. And then simply use `merge` function like below:

```
import pandas as pd
CommonCols = [col for col in df1.columns if col in df2.columns]
data = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=CommonCols )
```

or

```
data = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=[col for col in df1.columns if col in df2.columns])
```